# undefined behaviour: strtok

Tags: c, undefined-behavior, strtok

The function tokenize below is intended to set *size to 0 if sprt doesnt exist within str - as such if sprt points to "|" and str to "D AO D", chunk[1] is supposed to point to a NULL pointer and n to be set to 0:

```
void
tokenize(char *str,
         const char *sprt /*separator*/,
         char **buffer,
         int *size /*tokens length*/)
{
  char *chunk[2] = {NULL, NULL};

  //store str value into chunk[0]
  chunk[0] = calloc(strlen(str)+1, sizeof(char));
  strcpy(chunk[0], str);

  if (buffer!=NULL)
  {
    int sz = 0;
    chunk[1] = strtok(str, sprt);
    while (chunk[1]!=NULL)
    {
      buffer[sz] = calloc(strlen(chunk[1])+1, sizeof(char));
      strcpy(buffer[sz], chunk[1]);
      chunk[1] = strtok(NULL, sprt);
      sz++;
    }
  }
  else
  {
    *size=0;

    //if chunk is not NULL, the iteration begins => size > 0
    chunk[1] = strtok(str, sprt);

    while (chunk[1]!=NULL)
    {
      (*size)++;
      chunk[1] = strtok(NULL, sprt);
    }

    printf("size=%i\n", *size);
  }

  //restore str value from chunk[0]
  strcpy(str, chunk[0]);

  if (chunk[0]!=NULL) free(chunk[0]);
  if (chunk[1]!=NULL) free(chunk[1]);
}
```

However when testing the function within the following code, `bug: n really needs to be 0!` gets displayed, which means that `strtok` didn't work as I expected:

```
int main()
{
  char *test = calloc(7, sizeof(char));
  strcpy(test, "D AO D");

  int n;
  tokenize(test, "|", NULL, &n);
  if (n>0)
    printf("bug: n really needs to be 0!\n");
  else
    printf("no bug\n");
}
```

I don't really know what caused this UB. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Don't call `free(chunk[1])`  ; you should only `free` things you allocated with `malloc` family

Comment: This has nothing to do with any problem you're running into, but I always like to point out that `strdup()` is a better option than a `malloc()`/`strcpy()` combination.  Less error prone and more readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first `strtok` call returns a pointer to the original string `"D AO D"`, since there is no `"|"` delimiter in this string:

```
chunk[1] = strtok(str, sprt);
```

Then the `while` loop condition passes, since `chunk[1]` is a non-NULL pointer:

```
while (chunk[1]!=NULL)
{
  (*size)++;
  chunk[1] = strtok(NULL, sprt);
}
```

and `*size` is incremented in the first iteration. The next `strtok` call returns `NULL` as the terminating `'\0'` byte is encountered, and the loop is terminated due to unmet condition. Thus, `*size` becomes equal to `1`, and this is expected behaviour.

Comment: I didn't release that strtok returns the original string in the case of wrong delimiter. thanks.

Comment: @Kais: if there are no delimiters in the string, then the string is the sole token.